# jQuery Animate inline style issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cant fix one bug in my code. I create on click slide up/down div, but yet when i click it 4 times very fast my css top value is to height and function stop working. Can you please suggest me some solution or another way to handle this ?

Here is code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nav li a").click(function(event) {
    var page = $(this).attr("href")
    var topVal = $("#about").css("top")

    if (topVal != "-500px") {
      $(page).animate({
        top: "-=500"
      }, 500).css("top", "-500px")
    } else {
      $(page).animate({
        top: "+=500"
      }, 500)
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li><a href="#about">Start</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Start</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Start</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Start</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--  About Page-->
<section id="about" class="container-fluid col-md-9" style="top: -500px;">About
</section>
```

Comment: or better add a working example where we can see it happen

Comment: Well issue is quite simple, when i click on my nav links quite fast before div completly hide and top reach -500px  script consider if as true and add next -500px to top so !="-500px" is true and i cant slide it down

Comment: from the line `if (topVal != "-500px") {` it seems that you are certain that at some point, the top of your menu can be `-500px`. in that case, you dont need to add/subtract 500 points to slide the menu, just provide a static value `0px` and `-500px`, no need to use `-=` and `+=`

Comment: I'm not sure that your code work, you don't have `;` semicolons and you dont have `.` before class `nav` + you try to animate `href` value in else ??!! it's really strange.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki javascript adds semicolons on its own. the `.` before the `nav` is a good point though(pun intended)

Comment: nav is not a class - its <nav> i access all  li a inside nav. I just dont wanted to add very long html code. After Banana suggestion issue is resolved :) yeah i dunno why i  don’t figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nav li a").click(function(event) {
    var page = $(this).attr("href")
    var topVal = $("#about").css("top")

    if (topVal != "-500px") {
      $(page).animate({
        top: "-=500"
      }, 500).css("top", "-500px")
    } else {
      $(page).animate({
        top: "+=500"
      }, 500)
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  });
});
```

```css
section { position: relative; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li><a href="#about">Start</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Start</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Start</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Start</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--  About Page-->
<section id="about" class="container-fluid col-md-9" style="top: -500px;">About
</section>
```

I think this is better:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nav li a").click(function(event) {
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    $(href).toggleClass('offscreen');
    event.preventDefault()
  });
});
```

```css
section { position: relative; transition: 0.5s all; top:0 }
.offscreen { top: -500px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li><a href="#about">Start</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Start</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Start</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Start</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!--  About Page-->
<section id="about" class="container-fluid col-md-9 offscreen">About
</section>
```

Comment: Solution one present exaclly this bug which occure on my page. I resolve it already but i like very much your secound answer . So i mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Ah, I see the bug.  It's because if you click an item quickly, you could click it while an animation is currently playing, which your code doesn't account for.  Using an absolute value to transition to would fix it, or cancelling any currently running animation would also fix it in a different way.  Of course my second solution doesn't exhibit this bug because it is either offscreen or not, the animation is handled by the browser correctly.